# Free photo editor for Windows

Tags: windows, images, photography, image-editor

I'm looking for a free (not necessarily open source) program for editing JPG photos locally.

Requirements:

- a built-in file explorer for quick switching between photos, so I don't need to close and re-open the program to start editing another file (like Adobe's Mini Bridge)
- basic enhancing functionality, including color correction, straightening, perspective straightening (like Photoshop's Perspective Crop tool)
- detailed editing functionality, including fill removal for easily editing out objects from a photo (like Photoshop's Content-Aware filling)

The detailed editing functionality can be in a different program, as I don't use it as often. My primary focus is on quick running through hundreds of photos, which is why I need the built-in thumbnail bar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Photo editing software for Windows](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/340/photo-editing-software-for-windows)

Comment: @Chenmunka That question does not specify my particular requirements, and it suggests a price below $400 while I'm looking for freeware or open source software.

Comment: http://www.getpaint.net/index.html

Answer (score 6):

Having an Explorer window which you switch to with alt-tab and drag&dropping Images to GIMP (which can even be combined with alt-tab) is what I would suggest.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable alternative. I'll check if GIMP has all the features I need.

Answer (score 1):

I recently stumbled upon Chasys Draw, it fulfills your requirements, has an explorer mode, transform/perspective functions, and a lot of enhancing functionality, I cannot comment, but consider this an answer as it meets all your mentioned requirements.[Chasys Draw](http://www.jpchacha.com/chasysdraw/help.php?file=viewer_intro.htm)

Comment: I am exploring this program and looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't add comments yet, therefore an additional answer..

If GIMP, suggested by [Euri Pinhollow](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/27749/euri-pinhollow), doesn't do the trick, then maybe a combination of Windows Explorer + [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) will be sufficient for your needs.

A photo browsing alternative to Windows Explorer is [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com). IrfanView does also have photo editing capabilities (e.g. your requested straightening). For a list of some of the features have a look at their website.

Answer (score 0):

I think Photofiltre 7 is ok for you : http://www.photofiltre.com/

In the site you can choose between French or English.

There are two version : 1 free Photofiltre v7 and a commerciale version.

- Buit-in explorer, with many plugins (correction de perspective etc...)

[image: Buit-in explorer]

This image is in french but you can see "Explorer -> Dossier" and more.

I don't no if this prog is all you want ? (I not understand in English all the words :).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [FastStone Image Viewer](http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm), it's actually an image viewer, but it has a lot of edit tools and supports a wide array of formats (including PSD, TIFF, PDF...).

Pro:

- Very fast and lightweight
- Full screen viewer and editor with File explorer
- Image comparison
- EXIF and tag editor
- Dual monitor support (explorer + fullscreen editor)
- A lot more, check the website

Cons:

- No multi-layer capability
- Not free for commercial use ($34.95)
- A bit hard to use first time
- Only Windows